# Having errors when trying to compile these files zconf missing

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I've downloaded the source code to a long lost MMO I used to play when I was younger, and I'm following the poor instructions on the website to compile it which only says:

> The server needs Linux, MySQL development libraries and 32 bit gcc environment to compile.

That's the only instructions, so I've

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev
```

But if I try to do

```
sudo make
```

I get the error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-pointer-sign -O3 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -m32 -DSTAFF -o .obj/server.o -c server.c
In file included from server.c:46:0:
/usr/include/zlib.h:34:19: fatal error: zconf.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zconf.h"
```

I'm not sure if I'm even supposed to be using `make`, there is no `configure` file to run, any information on how to properly compile this would be great thanks

(Wasn't sure if Stackoverflow or Serverfault)

This is all the folder contents:

```
act.c      book.c        consistency.c       direction.h    flower_ppd.h  libload.h  mem.h          path.c           respawn.c       spell.h        tell.c
act.h      book.h        consistency.h       do.c           forest.c      light.c    merchant.c     path.h           respawn.h       staffer2.c     tell.h
alchemy.c  btrace.c      container.c         do.h           gatekeeper.c  light.h    merc.sql       pents.c          runtime         staffer3.c     teufel.c
area1.h    btrace.h      container.h         drdata.c       gwendylon.c   log.c      military.c     player.c         saltmine.c      staffer.c      teufel_pk.c
area2.c    caligar.c     create_account.c    drdata.h       ice.c         log.h      military.h     player_driver.c  sector.c        staffer_ppd.h  teufel_pk.h
area3.c    chat.c        create_armor.c      drvlib.c       ice_shared.c  lookup.c   mine.c         player_driver.h  sector.h        start          timer.c
area3.h    chat.h        create.c            drvlib.h       ignore.c      lookup.h   misc_ppd.h     player.h         see.c           statistics.c   timer.h
area.c     chatserver.c  create_character.c  dungeon.c      ignore.h      looping    mission_ppd.h  poison.c         see.h           statistics.h   todo.txt
area.h     clan.c        create.h            dungeon_tab.c  io.c          los.c      missions.c     poison.h         server.c        storage.sql    tool.c
arena.c    clan.h        create_tables.sql   edemon.c       io.h          los.h      motd.c         prof.c           server.h        store.c        tool.h
arkhata.c  clanlog.c     create_weapons.c    effect.c       item_id.h     lostcon.c  motd.h         professor.c      sewers.c        store.h        transport.c
arkhata.h  clanlog.h     database.c          effect.h       lab1.c        lostcon.h  motd.txt       prof.h           shrike.c        strategy.c     transport.h
badip.c    clanmaster.c  database.h          error.c        lab2.c        lq.c       my             punish.c         shrine.h        swamp.c        tunnel.c
badip.h    client.h      date.c              error.h        lab3.c        mail.c     MYSQLPASS      punish.h         sidestory.c     swear.c        two.c
balance.h  club.c        date.h              expire.c       lab4.c        mail.h     nomad.c        quest_exp.h      simple_baddy.c  swear.h        two_ppd.h
bank.c     club.h        death.c             expire.h       lab5.c        Makefile   nomad_ppd.h    questlog.c       skill.c         talk.c         update_server.c
bank.h     clubmaster.c  death.h             fdemon.c       lab.c         map.c      notify.c       questlog.h       skill.h         talk.h         warped.c
base.c     command.c     depot.c             fight.h        lab.h         map.h      notify.h       random.c         sleep.c         task.c         warrmines.c
bones.c    command.h     depot.h             fk.txt         libload.c     mem.c      palace.c       rdtsc.S          sleep.h         task.h         zones
```

Comment: Did you get it from a trusted source? (E.g. developers if it is open source)

Comment: @Lasoloz Yeah it's right off the developers website. [Here](http://brockhaus.org/astonia3.html)

Comment: Maybe you should try to contact the developer. I tried to compile, but there mysql dependencies, and I don't have time right now.

Comment: Might be a zlib1g-dev packaging issue. Solved symlinking zconf.h to /usr/include/: sudo ln -sfn /usr/include/*-linux-*/zconf.h /usr/include/